# Email address not retrieved when using PST-Parser, get Exchange code instead

Tags: c#, email, pst

I'm using [PST-Parser](https://github.com/Sharpiro/PST-Parser) to parse `.pst` files. Most of this is working, but I am having a problem when a message contains a recipient who is on an Exchange server, at least, I think that's the problem.

If I look at the raw message headers in Outlook, I can see something like this...

```
To: Jim1 <jim1@jim.com>
Cc: Jim2 <jim2@jim.com>, 
    Jim3 <jim3@jim.com>, 
    Someone Else <someone@else.co.uk>
```

As you can see, the email addresses for everyone @jim.com are stored in `SMTP` format, which is the format I need to display to the end user.

When I try to get the email address in code, I get something like this...

```
/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=404f8ca9734d4114bfbb1854d6336f55-jim1
```

The code I'm using to get the addresses is simple enough. Given a `Message` object, I can get (say) the first "To" recipient as follows...

```cs
Recipient recip = message.Recipients.To.First();
```

...and the email address as follows...

```cs
string email = recip.EmailAddress;
```

This works fine for most recipients, but for some, gives the odd code shown earlier. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736743/706346) (which relies on Outlook automation, which I can't use), the code shown above is a valid `EX` address. However, I need the `SMTP` address, eg `jim1@jim.com` to display to the end user.

Anyone any idea how I can get the `SMTP` address? It's clearly in the message headers, so should be available. What puzzles me is that the `EX` address returned doesn't even appear in the raw headers, so I have no idea where that is coming from.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You may have to order the To and CC and BCC fields manually.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Not sure what you mean. The usage of `First` I showed was just to simplify the code. However I access the recipients in the `To` and `CC` collections, the `EmailAddress` property shows the same. Please can you clarify what you mean. Thanks for the reply